# EnvDTE Retrieving the data type from a CodeElement

Tags: c#, envdte

I am using EnvDTE to generate some code in my latest project.

I have a reference to a CodeClass-Object for a given C#-Class but now I wanted to loop through all of its members (in codeClass.Members) and check their types.

However I can't manage to retrieve the type of the given member from the CodeElement-Object that I get when looping through codeClass.Members.

How can I retrieve the type (int, string etc.)?

PS: Reflection is not an option for my usecase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CodeElement has the Members property, which is a collection of CodeElement. CodeElement has a Kind property, from which you can know what kind of member we're talking about. Then you can cast each member to the appropriate interface and have a look around. Most subclasses have a Type property, with the info you are looking for.

I typed this in the Macro editor, in a module:

```
Public Sub DisplayStuff()

    Dim objTextSel As TextSelection
    Dim objCodeCls As CodeClass
    objTextSel = CType(DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection, TextSelection)
    objCodeCls = CType(objTextSel.ActivePoint.CodeElement(vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass), CodeClass)

    If objCodeCls Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Please launch this macro when the cursor is within a class")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each elt As CodeElement2 In objCodeCls.Members

        Select Case elt.Kind

            Case vsCMElement.vsCMElementVariable

                Dim v As CodeVariable2 = CType(elt, CodeVariable2)

                MsgBox(v.Name & " is a variable of type " & v.Type.AsString)

            Case vsCMElement.vsCMElementProperty

                Dim p As CodeProperty2 = CType(elt, CodeProperty2)

                MsgBox(p.Name & " is of type " & p.Type.AsString)
        End Select


    Next
End Sub
```

It simply takes the class that is where the cursor is in the editor and displays the type info for any field or property.